# Optimization Problem - Trigonometric Derivatives Application

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> You need to get from point A to point B as fast as possible. But there
>   is a circular lake between A and B. You can run twice as fast as you
>   can swim. At what angle (theta) should you swim?

Picture is a circle with a horizontal line drawn connecting point A (from left) to point B (to right). With angle tetha drawn on the left side where point A is.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the pond has radius $r$. We start from $A$. Assuming a solution symmetric to the $y$-axis:

- If we run on land, the fastest path towards $B$ is one the rim of the pond
- if we swim, the fastest path to reach the middle is to swim parallel to the $x$-axis

We just compare paths that start at $A$ and reach the middle at some height at point $(0, h)$.

[image: pond and path]
([Large version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37yrk.png))

Then the total running time is:
\begin{align}
t 
&= \frac{s_1}{2v} + \frac{s_2}{v} \\
&= \frac{r \alpha}{2v} + \frac{r \cos \alpha}{v}
\end{align}

Looking for extrema:
$$ 
0
= \frac{dt}{d\alpha} 
= \frac{r}{2v} - \frac{r \sin \alpha}{v} \iff \\
\frac{1}{2} = \sin \alpha \Rightarrow \\
\alpha = \frac{\pi}{6} = 30^\circ
$$

The value for $\alpha$ was taken from the triangle below:

[image: triangle for alpha]
([Large version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3U6p.png))

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply! The angle tetha is actually on the left side where you drew point A and then the hypothenuse would go all the way up from A till it reaches a point in the circle. So tetha would not be in the centre, but where point A is

Comment: If I understood $\theta$ you can convert like this: $\tan \theta = (r \sin \alpha) / (r - r \cos \alpha) = (\sin \alpha)/(1-\cos \alpha) = (1/2) / (1 - \sqrt{3}/2) = 1/(2 - \sqrt{3})$ then $\theta = 75^\circ$.

Comment: mvw sorry but I didn't understand what you meant by your last reply what are you considering to be your θ=75 in the diagram you drew?

Comment: I thought that was the theta you mentioned in your first comment here.

Comment: The α=30° is what I was looking for I was just wondering about the conversion you did to find the 75° here in the comments what angle does that refer to in your diagram?

Comment: It is the angle between $AO$ and $AD$ in the first image.